# Generic Repository with UnitOfWork with IoC Custom Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have a Generic Repository pattern with UnitOfWork and i am using IoC. Other than the base methods used by the repository, i have some custom methods. Instead of implementing the whole IRepository methods again, i have inherited from the GenericRepository class.

Here is my UnitofWork implementation:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<T> : IDisposable where T : DbContext
{
    int Save();
    T Context { get; }
}

public class UnitOfWork<T> : IUnitOfWork<T> where T : MyContext, new()
{
    private readonly T _context;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new T();
    }

    public UnitOfWork(T Context)
    {
        _context = Context;
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }


    public T Context
    {
        get
        {
            return _context;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This my Repository implementation:

```
    public interface IGenericRepository
{
    IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class;
    void Remove<T>(int id)where T : class;
    void Remove<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    void RemoveRange<T>(IList<T> entities) where T : class;
    T Find<T>(int id) where T : class;
    void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    void AddRange<T>(IList<T> entities) where T : class;
    void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}

  public class GenericRepository<C> : IGenericRepository where C : MyContext
{
    protected readonly C _context;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork<C> unitOfWork)
    {
        _context = unitOfWork.Context;
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
       return  _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Remove<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        T entity = _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Remove<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveRange<T>(IList<T> entities) where T : class
    {
        if (entities.Count > 0)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entities);
        }
    }

    public T Find<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void AddRange<T>(IList<T> entities) where T : class
    {
        _context.Set<T>().AddRange(entities);
    }

    public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of Custom-Repository:

```
public interface IUserAccountRepository : IGenericRepository
{
    UserAccount Find(string email, string password);
    bool CheckDuplicate(string email);
}

 public class UserAccountRepository<C> : GenericRepository<C> where C : CSharpAssigmentContext, IUserAccountRepository
{
    protected readonly C _context;

    public UserAccountRepository(IUnitOfWork<C> unitOfWork)
    {
        _context = unitOfWork.Context;
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
       return  _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find user by email and password
    /// </summary>
    public UserAccount Find(string email, string password)
    {
        return _context.Set<UserAccount>().Where(ua => ua.Email == email && ua.Password == password).FirstOrDefault(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check wether user exists or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool CheckDuplicate(string email)
    {
        return _context.Set<UserAccount>().Any(ua => ua.Email == email);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Remove<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        T entity = _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Remove<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveRange<T>(IList<T> entities) where T : class
    {
        if (entities.Count > 0)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entities);
        }
    }

    public T Find<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void AddRange<T>(IList<T> entities) where T : class
    {
        _context.Set<T>().AddRange(entities);
    }

    public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Here is my Unity IoC code:

```
    public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        //UnitOfWork and GenericRepository
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IUnitOfWork<CSharpAssigmentContext>),typeof(UnitOfWork<CSharpAssigmentContext>), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository), typeof(GenericRepository<CSharpAssigmentContext>), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        //I keep receiving compile ERROR here
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IUserAccountRepository), typeof(UserAccountRepository<CSharpAssigmentContext>), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        //Services
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IUsersAccountsService), typeof(UsersAccountsService), new TransientLifetimeManager());

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the code, i keep getting a compile time error for the following code:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IUserAccountRepository), typeof(UserAccountRepository<CSharpAssigmentContext>), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

The error is:

> The type MyContext can't be used as type parameter C in the generic type or method. There is no implicate reference conversion from MyContext to IMyClassRepository.

How to solve this error? Is my implementation correct for custom repositories?

Comment: Can you show your UserAccountRepository class signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foundation is wrong. A generic repository should have a generic *entity* parameter. Your "generic" repository does have methods with a generic parameter `T`, but there's no guarantee whatsoever that the same entity is always used. This is what the interface should look like:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> All();
    void Remove(int id);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    void RemoveRange(IList<TEntity> entities);
    TEntity Find(int id);
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void AddRange(IList<TEntity> entities);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

In fact, once you decide that you want a UoW/Repository layer on top of `DbContext/DbSet`, I don't see any reason to do it differently than [this standard example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). There you see a similar generic repository, besides a UoW that contains several repositories.

Having done that, what you call "`UserAccountRepository`", should be a service that *contains* a UoW, that can be injected by your IoC container:

```
public interface IUserAccountService // No repository!
{
    UserAccount Find(string email, string password);
    bool CheckDuplicate(string email);
}
```

Example implementation:

```
public class UserAccountService : IUserAccountService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork<CSharpAssigmentContext> _unitOfWork;

    public UserAccountService(IUnitOfWork<CSharpAssigmentContext> unitOfWork)
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

You see that in this UoW/Repository implementation the context isn't exposed. That's one of the purposes of this abstraction layer.

Comment: If you look at my UnityCode, you can see that i am actually implementing services. The reason i created a IUserAccountRepository was for custom methods only. When i implement the services, instead of using the IGenericRepository, i would use the custom repository. In your last piece of code, you used the UoW with the service. What i am doing here, applying another layer of abstraction. UoW -> DAL -> Repository -> Service -> Presention

Comment: My only question here is, why should i not have a custom repository and instead apply my custom methods in a service. I understand the purpose of the service layer is to expose business logic, but implemating all repository related methods in repository seems more logical.

Comment: Because that defeats the purpose of *generic* repositories. It also introduces a ever recurring decision: what do I put where? Some methods may seem fitting for a repository, some for a service, but there will always be a gray area.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there might be a mistake in your `UserAccountRepository` class definition:

```
public class UserAccountRepository<C> : GenericRepository<C>
    where C : CSharpAssigmentContext, IUserAccountRepository
```

That class definition can be read like that:

Type UserAccountRepository is a generic type with generic argument of type C; UserAccountRepository inherits from generic class GenericRepository with generic argument of type C; type C must inherit from class CSharpAssignmentContext and type C must implement interface IUserAccountRepository.

Removing `IUserAccountRepository` from type constraints for generic parameter `C` and adding it after GenericRepository after a comma should do the job:

```
public class UserAccountRepository<C> : GenericRepository<C>, IUserAccountRepository
    where C : CSharpAssigmentContext
```

Class definition now can be read like that:
Type UserAccountRepository is a generic type with generic argument of type C; UserAccountRepository inherits from generic class GenericRepository with generic argument of type C; type UserAccountRepository must implement interface IUserAccountRepository. Generic argument type (Type C) must inherit from class CSharpAssignmentContext.

When you inherit a class from generic class/interface together with other interfaces, you have to first specify what types you inherit from or implement, and only after that specify generic type constraints:

```
public class SomeImplementation<T1, T2> : ISomeInterface<T1>, IAnotherInterface<T2>, IDisposable, ICloneable 
    where T1 : IAbstraction
    where T2 : class
```

Comment: It seems that i have updated my question with a workaround that was working. I have updated the question now. What i am doing in my custom repository is that i am inheriting from the GenericRepository and the IUserAccountRepository. When i inherit from the Generic Repository alone, it works fine, but as soon as i inherit from the IUserAccountRepository, i receive the error mentioned in the question